# Why canvas stop clearing rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I try to animate simple object in canvas and it works at start but after some time it stops to clear rectangles and just continue to fill new rectangles.
At least i think it stop clearing maybe is something else. Can anyone help me? There are no console errors.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x=100;
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0,0,window.innerHeight,window.innerWidth);
    c.beginPath();
    c.fillRect(x,100,100,100);
    x+=2;
}
animate();
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
canvas{
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: First of all, you should run `requestAnimationFrame` at the end of your function not the beginning.

Comment: @lbu does it matter? `requestAnimationFrame` puts the given function in a stack and it'll be executed after the thread 'ends', so it shouldn't matter where you put the call to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @Al.G in a comment, your `height` and `width` parameters are reversed in the `clearRect()` call. Swapping them `c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);` will fix the problem.

I generally clear with `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` rather than non-canvas properties such as `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` since the `canvas` properties will always match its dimensions, reduce dependency on external/global variables and don't require thought beyond that.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 100;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.beginPath();
    c.fillRect(x, 100, 100, 100);
    x += 2;
}

animate();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Actually OP's problem was the inverted order of the arguments `window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth`. I guess it would have worked with them, even when not using the canvas' properties.

Comment: "since the canvas properties will always match its dimensions" is true only for untransformed matrix.

Comment: @Kaiido Transformations happen on the context, not on the canvas object itself. Once you transform the context, the coordinate pair `0, 0` is the part that isn't accurate, not the height and width. But it doesn't hurt to point out the issue.

Comment: clearRect is based on the current matrix. If you scale rotate or translate you won't be clearing what you wish with 0,0,w,h

Comment: Yes, I think we agree on that. I don't see what that has to do with the statement in my post, which is talking about `canvas.width` and `canvas.height`, not the context. `window.innerWidth` will change if the user resizes the screen, while `canvas.width` remains the same, for example, leading to unexpected behavior. I'm not saying "`ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` will always clear the context" but I am saying "`canvas.width` will always match the canvas width while a global var like `window.innerWidth` won't".

Answer (score 0):

I will only add this here because the accepted answer fixed your problem accidentally.

The problem is that your reversed the parameters of clearRect;

You did:

```
c.clearRect(0,0,window.innerHeight,window.innerWidth);
```

While the answer was:

```
c.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
```